# Getting a 404 when trying to load /wp-admin/plugin-install.php

Tags: plugins, 404-error, installation

I am not sure why, but the back-end of my site is running slow... even though it's running slow, all pages still load, except this one `/wp-admin/plugin-install.php` (the add new plugin page).

I checked and the file is present in `wp-admin`, with the correct permissions, every time I try to load the page I get a 404.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: In my case, it started after enabling ssl on wordpress 4.7.3.